# Seleccionar un valor aleatorio de una Matrix N*M

Tags: python

Tengo que crear una matriz MxN de puros 0 donde el ancho y el largo lo ingresa el usuario, y el programa debe reemplazar alguno de los 0 de manera aleatoria por un 1 y otro por un 2.
Hasta ahora he logrado imprimir la matriz de puros 0 pero nose como definir una posición aleatoria considerando filas y columnas.. cualquier tip sirve!

---------------CODIGO----------------

```
area=[]                                             
largo=int(raw_input("Ingrese el LARGO del cuadrante: "))
alto=int(raw_input("Ingrese el ALTO del cuadrante: "))
for x in range(alto):
  area.append(["0"]*largo)
def imprimir_area(area):
    for row in area:
    print(" ".join(row))

imprimir_area(area)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto sólo te servirá si el alto y el largo son mayores que 0 y si no te importa que se sobreescriba el primer valor, en el caso que coincidan las posiciones generadas:

```
from random import randint
area[randint(0,alto-1)][randint(0,largo-1)]='1'
area[randint(0,alto-1)][randint(0,largo-1)]='2'
imprimir_area(area)
```

`randint` te devuelve un número entero aleatorio en un rango dado.

Si no deseas que se sobreescriban, puedes utilizar sample:

```
from random import sample
a, b = sample(range(alto - 1), 2)
c, d = sample(range(largo - 1), 2)
area[a][c] = '1'
area[b][d] = '2'
imprimir_area(area)
```

`random.sample()` te permite obtener valores aleatorios no repetidos de una secuencia dada, por eso `a` y `b` (valores aleatorios para las posiciones de las filas) y `c` y `d`  (valores aleatorios para las posiciones de las columnas), no coincidirán; así evitarás que coincidan, a menos que tengas una matriz de 1x1.

Comment: Eso lo iba a aclarar en la solución, pero si @Zilver no lo especifica en su pregunta, entonces la solución no tiene por qué evitar que se sobreescriban los datos.

Comment: OK, agregué una segunda opción que tiene en cuenta lo que explica @Pollo en sus comentarios.

Comment: Gracias!!! se pasaron!!